# table styling - is it possible for a td:hover rule to override a tr:hover?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it's possible to have a table styled with `:hover` background rules for both a tr and a td with certain class so that when the particular td is hovered on, only that element gets the background applied and not the tr it's within.

So for example:

```css
tr:hover {
    background: blue;
}
td.something:hover {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="something"></td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Here I'd like the table to highlight the row if the first two td elements are hovered, but not on the third td with the `something` css class.

I was wondering if the `:not` selector could help somehow, but I haven't come up with a way yet. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: `tr:hover td:not(.something)`

Comment: Just to be sure: you want the entire row in blue background when you hover the first 2 cells and the entire row in yellow background when you hover the last cell?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```css
tr:hover {
    background: blue;
}
tr:hover td.something {
    background: #FFF;  
}

tr:hover td.something:hover {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td class="something">dddd</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it possible. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Maro94/s3n47hzc/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      first td
    </td>
    <td>
      second td
    </td>
    <td>
      third td
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
   td:hover{
      background-color:red;
    }
    tr:hover{
      background-color:yellow;
    }
    td{
      border:1px solid black;
      padding: 5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can except tags with your css class as following

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

tr:hover td:not(.something) {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td class="something">Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Or if you want to some cells with bg yellow and some with blue same time:

```css
tr:hover td:not(.something) {
    background: blue;
}

tr:hover td:not(.anotherthing) {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr> 
        <td class="anotherthing">Cell 1</td>
        <td class="anotherthing">Cell 2</td>
        <td class="something">Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```